# Django Nose how to write this test?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, nose

I'm completely new to **testing** in Django. I have started by installing **nose** and **selenium** and now I want to test the following code *(below)* It sends an SMS message.

This is the actual code:

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def process_all(request):
    """
    I process the sending for a single or bulk message(s) to a group or single contact.
    :param request:
    """
    #If we had a POST then get the request post values.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        batches = Batch.objects.for_user_pending(request.user)
        for batch in batches:
            ProcessRequests.delay(batch)
            batch.complete_update()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/reports/messages/')
```

So where do I start? This is what I have done so far...

1) created a folder called tests and added **init**.py.

2) created a new python file called test_views.py (I'm assuming that's correct).

Now, how do I go about writing this test?

**Could someone show me with an example of how I write the test for the view above?**

Thank you :)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/ & https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/overview/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, you don't need `selenium` for testing views. Selenium is a tool for high-level in-browser testing - it's good and useful when you are writing UI tests simulating a real user.

Nose is a tool that `makes testing easier` by providing features like automatic test discovery, supplies a number of helper functions etc. The best way to integrate nose with your django project is to use [django_nose](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose) package. All you have to do is to:

1. add `django_nose` to `INSTALLED_APPS`
2. define `TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'`

Then, every time you run `python manage.py test <project_name>` nose will be used to run your tests.

---

So, speaking about testing this particular view, you should test:

- [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator work - in other words, unauthenticated user will be redirected to the login page
- if `request.method` is not POST, no messages sent + redirect to `/reports/messages`
- sending SMS messages when POST method is used + redirect to `/reports/messages`

Testing first two statements is pretty straight-forward, but in order to test the last statement you need to provide more details on what is `Batch`, `ProcessRequests` and how does it work. I mean, you probably don't want to send real SMS messages during testing - this is where [mocking](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) will help. Basically, you need to mock (replace with your own implementation on the fly) `Batch`, `ProcessRequests` objects. Here's an example of what you should have in `test_views.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.test.client import Client
from django.test import TestCase


class ProcessAllTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')

    def test_login_required(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('process_all'))
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/login')

    def test_get_method(self):
        self.client.login(username='john', password='johnpassword')
        response = self.client.get(reverse('process_all'))
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/reports/messages')

        # assert no messages were sent

    def test_post_method(self):
        self.client.login(username='john', password='johnpassword')

        # add pending messages, mock sms sending?

        response = self.client.post(reverse('process_all'))
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/reports/messages')

        # assert that sms messages were sent
```

Also see:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/
- [Django Testing Guide](http://toastdriven.com/blog/2011/apr/10/guide-to-testing-in-django/)
- [Getting Started with Python Mock](http://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2011/02/26/python-python-mock-cheat-sheet/)

Hope that helps.